# SAS using global variables in conditional comparisons of characters

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I have an if statement that checks whether a global variable is yes/no

The global variable is the output from a previous macro

Why is it when I use quotes around the 'Y' or 'N' it doesn't work - i've never seen this in any other progamming language. I've always had to use quotes for character variables

i.e. this does not work

```
%if &errorflag='Y' %then %do;
```

but this works:

```
%if &errorflag=Y %then %do;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Macros are nothing but a text substitution engine.  So the value contained in `&errorflag` is `Y` and not `'Y'`.  Obviously `Y ^= 'Y'`.

This would work

```
%if "&errorflag" = "Y" %then %do;
```

It surrounds the value in `&errorflag` in quotes.

```
%if "%upcase(&errorflag)" = "Y" %then %do;
```

Might be a safer comparison.

Comment: i see. i dont think i understand macro variables properly, i assumed it was an object stored

Comment: the best way to think of macros is that they provide a way to write SAS code for you.  Macro routines dynamically create SAS code that then gets passed to the SAS interpreter.

Comment: thankyou for your explanation. makes a lot more sense to me now

Comment: Nice explanation.  I've found it's a good habit to put the `%upcase()` within the double quotes though.  Otherwise when you go to use something like `%trim()` you don't get the results you expect (as the whitespace inside the double quotes won't get trimmed).

Comment: I wouldn't suggest using the quotes to make it safer; use macro quoting (`%quote()`) or string (`str()`) instead.

Comment: Also worth noting, for the sake of the OP, that the use of double quotes `"&errorflag" = "Y"` is significant, as single quotes `'&errorflag' = 'Y'` would not allow the macro variable to be resolved, whereas double quotes do.